# Check if Swift array contains instance of object

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3, equatable

How does one check if a Swift array contains a particular instance of an object? Consider this simple example:

```
class Car {}

let mazda = Car()
let toyata = Car()

let myCars = [mazda, toyata]

myCars.contains(mazda) // ERROR!
```

My investigations have let me to the conclusion that the `Car` class must adopt the `Equatable` protocol. It seems to be the case:

```
class Car: Equatable {
    static func ==(lhs: Car, rhs: Car) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Then `myCars.contains(mazda)` does indeed return `true`.

However, the implementation of `==` is obviously not what I want. What I really want it to return is the answer to the question: Are `lhs` and `rhs` the same `Car` instances?

Is it really that complicated?

Thanks!

Comment: *"Are lhs and rhs the same Car instances?"* - No, the question should be "do lhs and rhs represent the same equivalent Cars?". They don't need to be the same instances to be equal.

Comment: No, that is not what I want. In my case (not the toy example with cars), I really do want to know if they are the same instance. Anyway, problem solved with the === operator. Never heard of that one before.

Comment: That's not how it is supposed to work. You are violating the semantics of the `Equatable` protocol (and hence the Hashable protocol). You are going to cause some strange, very hard to track bugs in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the *identity operator*

```
static func ==(lhs: Car, rhs: Car) -> Bool {
   return lhs === rhs
}
```

Or even without `Equatable`

```
myCars.contains{ $0 === mazda }
```

Edit: But a better solution is to implement equality rather than identity, for example a `vendor` and `type` property in the class

```
static func ==(lhs: Car, rhs: Car) -> Bool {
   return lhs.vendor == rhs.vendor && lhs.type == rhs.type
}
```

Comment: Don't do this. It violates the semantics of the Equatable (and Hashable) protocols.

Comment: @rmaddy I know, but the OP wants a "cheap" solution.

Comment: What else could you do, then? I have a Graph class which is basically an array of Vertex objects. How would you answer: Does the Graph object contain a specific Vertex?

Comment: Nope, I don't want a cheap solution. I want a good solution :-)

Comment: @MichaelKnudsen If you want a good solution, don't implement `==` by using `===`. Start by updating your question with your actual code instead of the fake "Car" sample. The `==` must check if two objects are equivalent, not the same instance. You do this by comparing property values.

Comment: If there are properties in the class, compare them.

Answer (score 3):

```
===
```

operator in Swift checks whether two object references both refer to the same object instance.

So your `Equatable` could look like this:

```
   static func ==(lhs: Car, rhs: Car) -> Bool {
        return lhs===rhs
    }
```

I do **not** recommend this approach. `Equatable`'s purpose is not to evaluate references to the same object.

Comment: Don't do this. It violates the semantics of the Equatable (and Hashable) protocols.

Comment: I agree with you that it somehow feels wrong to use Equatable. I am (trying to) make a simple implementation of an undirected graph. Basically just a list of vertices, and I want to ask: Does my graph contain a particular vertex?

Comment: But why does it need to be the same reference? Vertices properties can be compared by x and y values. @vadian provides an example above of equality property comparison.